# Using/avoiding "the" after/before possessive construction with"of"

Tags: definite-article, possessives

I am wondering when we should use "the" after a possessive construction with "of"?

Is this necessary to use/avoid "the" before a possessive construction with "of"?

For example, consider:

1. the observation of the instability
2. the observation of an instability
3. an observation of the instability
4. an observation of an instability
5. observations of instabilities
6. the observations of instabilities
7. the observations of the instabilities

which one is intrinsically incorrect?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You mean something like this: "It is the bone of the dog" Instead of "It is the bone of dog"? Can you give some examples?

Comment: We need more context to justify *answering*, but @Catija's suggestion could perhaps be brought into focus by comparing, say, [*Racing is the sport of kings*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22racing+is+the+sport+of+kings%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) with [*Religion is the opiate of **the** people*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22is+the+opiate+of+the+people%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1).

Comment: Thanks @FumbleFingers I was struggling. The only thing I could think of was "It is the order of the court that..."

Comment: @Catija: They may *not* be good examples, since without clarification, we're just guessing what exactly OP is asking about. And let's not forget both my examples are fixed, idiomatically established "sayings", which may not reflect any underlying principles applicable to other contexts. Another potentially relevant contrastable pair might by *I've booked my holiday for the beginning of [**the**] summer*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I think the problem is that the use of the "of" possessive can seem clunky when used in cases it's not a set phrase. Saying "the summer's beginning" sounds odd... as much as saying "the bone of the dog" instead of "the dog's bone". I'm sure there are cases where they are largely interchangeable but I can't think of one at the moment.

Comment: For example, consider: 1- the observation of the instability 2- the observation of an instability 3- an observation of the instability 4- an observation of an instability 5-observations of instabilities 6- the observations of instabilities 7- the observations of the instabilities; which one is intrinsically incorrect?

Comment: @Sara: I think Catija and I are really just "passing time" while we wait for you to clarify the question text. If your comment represents the essence of what you're asking about, you need to edit it into the question text itself (all these comments are quite likely to be deleted by moderators at some point).

Comment: @FumbleFingers
OK you are right and sorry for inconvenience.

Comment: I don't think any of those are "intrinsically" correct... it depends on what you're actually trying to say. You've also omitted "the/an observation of instability". But I think that you should avoid discussing the article before the first word unless that's what you're asking about... because that's a separate issue.

Comment: @Sara: Your question is now much improved. I agree with Catija that definite / indefinite / zero article before the first word (and singular / plural for *observation* and *instability*) don't directly affect "correctness". But I suppose if it's not obvious to you, explaining *why* this is so could reasonably be addressed by a comprehensive answer.

Comment: @FumbleFingers
I just thought maybe there are some kind of rules which must be applied to the "of" constructions. For example, if we use a definite article before the first noun, should we use a definite article before the second noun as well? Is this necessary to use the same kind of article for both nouns concurrently?

Comment: @Sara: I wouldn't like to *swear* there are no counter-examples, but I think the choice of "determiner" *and* pluraility form both nouns in your example are entirely independent. In each case it simply depends on whether you're talking about one or multiple *observations / instabilities*, and whether the context explicitly or implicitly references one (or one *set, group*) of them in particular *(**the**)*, or just *any (**a**)* .

Answer (score 1):

All seven are fine, depending on the context.  See your favorite textbook about the use of the definite article.