dropping 'the' after 'of'
Is there any rule for dropping 'the' after 'of' in the following that can be used to infer other general cases:
the rate of change
the amplitude of deflection
the sections of metal bar

There’s no rule that I can think of. Indeed, for this native speaker of American English your three examples happen to span the possibilities. *Rate of the change sounds unacceptable (and thus the is prohibited), *the amplitude of deflection sounds wrong (so the is required), and the sections of [the] metal bar can go either way: with the it refers to sections of a particular bar and without the it refers to sections of a material or substance in a particular form.

See e.g. https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/353757/using-the-with-return-of-someone-something https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/64025/using-avoiding-the-after-before-possessive-construction-withof https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/282573/what-is-the-difference-between-of-of-the-the-of-the-and-the-of etc https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/245094/use-of-the-after-of

@PaulTanenbaum  Thanks for your answer. The three examples provided are indicative of the speaker being American?

@PaulTanenbaum Thanks for your answer. The three examples provided are indicative of the speaker being American?
